# Apparent bug with # of pending suggestion edits notification

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits

On the [hermeneutics.SE](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/), I am getting the pending suggested edit notice, but there aren't actually any I can approve.

[image: Pending edit notice]

The notice appeared right after I submit a tag wiki edit for approval, so the pending one is probably my own.  This didn't happen before I earned the "approve tag wiki edits" privilege, which I did happened today.  Thus, I think it is probably something having enough rep to approve the tag wiki but not enough to have the suggestion auto approved causes the system to think you should be able to approve it even though it is your own edit.